# PHP: add/edit output tags with DomXPath

Tags: php

I should be able to modify the output obtained with the following query:

```
$ods22_tmp_t =$finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'PPToggle')]");
```

the output is as follows:

```
              <tr class="PPToggle" CO="8465">
                    <td PT="0" PABloccato="True" Validato="False" MeseValidato="False"><div title="HD09001300 dalle ore 09:00 alle ore 13:00" class="cellePiano" PT="1428" ColoreTesto="#000000" ColoreSfondo="">
                        HD09001300
                    </div><div title="HD14001800 dalle ore 14:00 alle ore 18:00" class="cellePiano" PT="142" ColoreTesto="#000000" ColoreSfondo="">
                        HD14001800
                    </div></td><td PT="0" PABloccato="True" Validato="False" MeseValidato="False"><div title="HD10001400 dalle ore 10:00 alle ore 14:00" class="cellePiano" PT="142219" ColoreTesto="#000000" ColoreSfondo="">
                        HD10001400
                    </div><div title="HD15001900 dalle ore 15:00 alle ore 19:00" class="cellePiano" PT="142820" ColoreTesto="#000000" ColoreSfondo="">
                        HD15001900
                    </div></td><td PT="0" PABloccato="True" Validato="False" MeseValidato="False"><div title="HD13001700 dalle ore 13:00 alle ore 17:00" class="cellePiano" PT="142882" ColoreTesto="#000000" ColoreSfondo="">
                        HD13001700
                    </div><div title="HD18002200 dalle ore 18:00 alle ore 22:00" class="cellePiano" PT="14287" ColoreTesto="#000000" ColoreSfondo="">
                        HD18002200
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
```

I would like to add this tag between TR and TD:

```
<th>Operator</th>
```

How can I specify that I want to add a tag between two in particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the element your after, and then use `insertBefore()` to position this new node in the document (using `$node->firstChild` to position it first)...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$ods22_tmp_t = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, 'PPToggle')]");

foreach($ods22_tmp_t as $node) {
    $th = $dom->createElement("th", "Operator");
    $node->insertBefore($th, $node->firstChild);
}
```